# CyberStart Assess questions

Tags: javascript

for questions 5,8,10 and 12

Question 12 is somesort of javascript to launch a rocket.

```
            // Launch the rocket!
            var launchRocket = function (sequence) {
                if (sequence === 321) {
                var _$_f307 = ["\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x4E\x61\x6D\x65", "\x61\x6E\x69\x6D\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x2D\x77\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77", "\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x4E\x61\x6D\x65", "\x62\x6F\x64\x79", "\x61\x6E\x69\x6D\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x2D\x77\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77\x20\x61\x6E\x69\x6D\x61\x74\x65", "\x70\x72", "\x6f\x70\x33", "\x6c\x30\x66\x66", "\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C", "\x72\x6F\x63\x6B\x65\x74\x2D\x63\x6F\x64\x65"];
                document[_$_f307[3]][_$_f307[2]](_$_f307[1])[0][_$_f307[0]] = _$_f307[4];
                var e = _$_f307[5];
                var x = _$_f307[6];
                var n = _$_f307[7];
                document[_$_f307[3]][_$_f307[2]](_$_f307[1])[0][_$_f307[0]] = e + x + n;
            }
        }
```

Thats the javascript given, but not sure if im supposed to add something to execute it

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. If this is a homework question that you don't understand, you should talk to your teacher.

Comment: https://assess.joincyberdiscovery.com/, for this website theres a challenge, if you sign up and see q12 requires me to launch an animation of a rocket, but im not sure how, the javascript above was found in the chromes inspect element

Comment: @Billybob123 It's your challenge....not much of a challenge if you have someone else do it for you...

Comment: i can use help but ok

Answer (score 0):

**Question 12:**
All you have to do for this one is convert the \x63\x6C\x61\x73\etc. from hexadecimal to text using an online converter(http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/hexadecimal/). You will get:

```
var launchRocket = function (sequence) {

                if (sequence === 321) {

                var _$_f307 = ["className", "animation-window",
                "getElementsByClassName", "body", "animation-window animate",
                "l3", "vit", "at3way", "innerHTML", "rocket-code"];

                document[_$_f307[3]][_$_f307[2]](_$_f307[1])[0][_$_f307[0]] = _$_f307[4];

                var e = _$_f307[5];

                var x = _$_f307[6];

                var n = _$_f307[7];

                document[_$_f307[3]][_$_f307[2]](_$_f307[9])[0][_$_f307[8]] = e + x + n;

            }

        }
```

Paste this in the console.

then type `launchRocket(321)` into the console right after. This should launch the rocket, revealing the code.

I did this today and got the code, but when I submitted it said I had the wrong code. Let me know if it works for you.

**Question 10:** This one's easy once you know what the commands do. You have the search through the directories until you find the text file, just trial and error.

- `pwd`- Prints the directory you are currently in
- `ls` - lists all items in the current directory
- `cd` - changes your current directory
- `cat`- reads the file

I think you can do this without the answer but i'll be happy to help some more if you need.

I've not been able to do 5 and 8 either, have you made any progress?

Answer (score 0):

I've done all of the questions except 9, 10 and 13. 
q 5: u go into inspect and the line of code that controls the enter button the the fridge. i cant remember but I think u have to replace the disable with enable.
here's the line you need to change:
`<input type="submit" value="Enter" class="btn" disabled="true">`

q8: I forgot how I did this one lol. I think u go in the inspect element and change the line of code which sets all lights to turn when a certain amount of them turn off.

sorry for my bad explaining hope this helps. good luck!

thx for the help on q 10

Answer (score 0):

For Q5, in the code somewhere is this:

```
                            <div class="actions">
                                <!-- Developer notes: This will be disabled if page not accessed from technician's laptop. -->
                                <input type="submit" value="Enter" class="btn" disabled="true">
```

(look under the challenge module section of the code and keep expanding to find this section) 
To complete this challenge, you have to open the fridge by enabling the enter button. You will then receive the code. To enable the Enter button, change 'disabled' to 'abled'> This should enable the button which you can now click on.

For Q8: turn lights off until the emergency response kicks in. At the top of the light grid is a web address bar. When the emergency response kicks in, it should display this:
    https://supercitylights.com/lights?all_on=true

To get the code, change 'all_on' to  'all_off'.

For Q10: use the commands (pwd,cd,ls,cat) to open folders in the console. I think you only need to use ls and cat.
ls - lists folders
cat - displays files in a readable mode.

Using these commands, such through all the folders and open each file until you find one giving you a code.

For Q12: type 'launchRocket(321)' into the console and watch the rocket launch to reveal the code.

I hope this has been helpful. :)